# Adding a second use of a date input which uses JS makes neither of them work

Tags: javascript, html

I have three selects, one for month, one for day, and one for year. I've got some basic JS which updates a text input box when one of the three selects is modified.

HTML:

```
<select name="month" class="month" onchange="setDate(this,day,year)">
    <option value="1">January</option>...
</select>
<select name="day" class="day" onchange="setDate(month,this,year)">
    <option value="1">1</option>...
</select>
<select name="year" class="year" onchange="setDate(month,day,this)">
    <option value="2012">2012</option>...
</select>
<input type="text" name="hidden" value="" />
```

This is working perfectly fine, but I want to add another set of these three inputs. When I do this (make another copy of the HTML above), neither of them work. That is, the text input box is not being updated/given the date as the selects are modified (selected).

JavaScript (relevant parts):

```
function setDate(month_selection, day_selection, year_selection)
{
    //Month, Day and Year variables created

    form.hidden.value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
```

Any ideas on why it's only working when I have just one copy of the HTML above and how I would fix this so I can have two sets of these selects?

EDIT:
I've fixed the problem by giving the input as well as the selects different names for each "copy" of the HTML.

I'm now having a new problem, which is how to update the correct text box depending on which input is being changed.

If I put this at the end of my setDate function:

```
form.hidden.value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
form.hidden_two.value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
```

It will update the text boxes for both of them when either is changed (obviously). Does anyone know a way to make it update the correct text box?

Comment: make sure that the name property of text input box is different.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having another problem now, please read my edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but are you changing name of your new input? If you have two 'hidden' input boxes then it wont work.

New stuff :

Of course you will have to change names to all fields = month, day, year and hidden. Then inside your JS function you can determine which field change prompted script execution... I would think something like this:

```
function setDate(month_selection, day_selection, year_selection)
{
   if (month_selection.name=='month'){
      var hidden = document.getElementsBynName('hidden');
   } 
   if (month_selection.name=='month_two'){
      var hidden = document.getElementsByName('hidden_two');
   } 

//Month, Day and Year variables created

   hidden.value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
```

This is not an exact solution, just a pointer to how you can solve it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having another problem now, please read my edit. :)

Comment: Hi, read my edit. It was written to answer your previous question but I think it will help with current.